# Does Linux have an Equivalent of Windows PMTU Blackhole Router Discovery?

Tags: linux, networking

Under windows there is a registry setting to enable "Blackhole Router Detection", enabling path MTU discovery to function when there are misconfigured routers / firewalls in the path blocking the ICMP fragmentation needed messages.

http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc958871.aspx

Is there an equivalent feature that can be enabled on Linux?

I am running Ubuntu 9.10 Kernel 2.6.31-14-generic and would be very interested in any commands to enable / monitor this behaviour or any links to articles / howtos explaining how it is implemented.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Yes, you can.

To quote from [the linux kernel mailing list](http://lkml.kernel.org/g/1e41a3230805221019u4c739527u2a9c1217d1c7411c@mail.gmail.com) in 2008:

> From: John Heffner `<johnwheffner@...>`
>   Subject: Re: PMTU Discovery - Does it work?
>   Date: Thursday, May 22, 2008 - 1:19 pm
>   Message-ID: `<1e41a3230805221019u4c739527u2a9c1217d1c7411c@mail.gmail.com>`
>
> [...]
>
> This is a well known issue (RFC 2923), and was the motivation for the
>   development of MTU probing (RFC 4821), enabled with `tcp_mtu_probing`.

John Heffner wrote the changes to the linux kernel in 2007.

so to turn on `tcp_mtu_probing`

```
# echo 2 > /proc/sys/net/ipv4/tcp_mtu_probing
```

Possible values

```
0: disabled
1: enabled when black hole detected
2: always enabled
```

Comment: link for your source please?

Comment: http://kerneltrap.org/mailarchive/linux-net/2008/5/22/1910924

Comment: thanks!  added that link into the answer and tweaked the formatting a bit, hope you don't mind.

Comment: https://mellowd.co.uk/ccie/?tag=rfc4821 has a nice explanation, and a nice way to debug what is going on using "ip route get" and "ip -6 route show cache".  Also, despite the name, net.ipv4.tcp_mtu_probing will affect IPv6 as well.

Answer (score 1):

- RFC2923 - TCP Problems with Path MTU
  Discovery, September 2000
- RFC4821 - Packetization Layer Path
  MTU, March 2007 (takes into account
  ICMP blackhole)

I think support to ICMP blackhole recovery (as indicated in RFC4821, but complete RFC ¿is not implemented?) was added to Linux kernel 2.6.17. It can be enabled by means of `tcp_mtu_probing option`.

More info: http://staff.psc.edu/mathis/MTU/

I haven't found more updated info so far (additional info is welcome).

Answer (score -1):

The last information that I knew was that Linux had no support for PMTU blackhole router discovery.

This is due to the Linux non-compliance of RFC 2923.

Comment: RFC 2923 is informational and lists a number of common issues. What do you mean when you claim non-compliance to this?